# WooCommerce - Adding product category to order-details table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

---

**Here's what I'm attempting to do and where.**

In the check out process for an order, in the plug-in WooCommerce; you are taken to a page when the check out is process is complete. It displays an overview of the order details. The template file used to output this page is order-details.php.

**Here's what I'd like to add**

I would like to display the product's product category like so:

[image]

**This is area of code I'm attempting to add to, the first section of the order details table.**

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {

        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );
            $item_meta    = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item['item_meta'], $_product );

            ?>
            <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
                <td class="product-name">
                    <?php
                        if ( $_product && ! $_product->is_visible() )
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item['name'], $item );
                        else
                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink( $item['product_id'] ), $item['name'] ), $item );

                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $item['qty'] ) . '</strong>', $item );
```

**This is my understanding so far;**

- That a custom query is being applied.
- That for each product listed details are being echoed.
- That a WooCommerce Class is being used to get specific product meta.

My understandings are observations at my current knowledge level.

**What I was hoping was that I could use something like**

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', ' <strong class="product-category">' . e_( $item['product_cat'] ) . '</strong>', $item );
```

I can't find a more relevant filter and I'm really not sure that ['product_cat'] is even relevant here. This is an example of the way I'm attempting to solve my requirement.

As you can tell, I don't work in PHP full time. I'm learning as much as I can when I can. Advise would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi John. Can you edit to explain what you are trying to add and where? A screenshot would not be a terrible idea. ;) Although I am inclined to think that we'll be adding the category name to the item name via the `woocommerce_order_item_name` filter.

Comment: Thanks! I've added a screenshot. Understood that I might use the `woocommerce_order_item_name`. I'm going to go check it out now. Please let me know if you think I should add more to my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you might add the product categories to the Product title. I don't particularly like how it is outputting for me, but then I am testing it on a variable subscription, so that is amending its own data. This would go in your theme's functions.php

```
function kia_woocommerce_order_item_name( $name, $item ){

    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $tax = 'product_cat';

    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $tax, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

    if( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms )) {
        $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($tax);
        $name .= '<label>' . $taxonomy->label . ': </label>' . implode( ', ', $terms );
    }

    return $name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'kia_woocommerce_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
```

Otherwise you could copy the `order-details.php` template into your own theme (so `yourtheme/woocommerce/order/order-details.php` and add the code directly. This would give you more control over where you want the category to appear since there aren't a lot of hooks available in this section, but put you at risk if WooCommerce ever modifies this code. I have worked on a few sites that broke because the the theme was using outdated template.

Any way, an example would be:

```
<?php
/**
 * Order details
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.2.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $woocommerce;

$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
?>
<h2><?php _e( 'Order Details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
<table class="shop_table order_details">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="product-name"><?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <th class="product-total"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <?php
        if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) foreach ( $totals as $total ) :
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {

            foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );
                $item_meta    = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item['item_meta'], $_product );

                ?>
                <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
                    <td class="product-name">
                        <?php
                            if ( $_product && ! $_product->is_visible() )
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item['name'], $item );
                            else
                                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_permalink( $item['product_id'] ), $item['name'] ), $item );

                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html', ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $item['qty'] ) . '</strong>', $item );

                            $item_meta->display();

                            // insert product category here
                            $tax = 'product_cat';
                            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $_product->id, $tax, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );

                            if( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms )) {
                                $taxonomy = get_taxonomy($tax);
                                echo '<strong>' . $taxonomy->label . ': </strong>' . implode( ', ', $terms );
                            }

                            // end edit

                            if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $_product->is_downloadable() && $order->is_download_permitted() ) {

                                $download_files = $order->get_item_downloads( $item );
                                $i              = 0;
                                $links          = array();

                                foreach ( $download_files as $download_id => $file ) {
                                    $i++;

                                    $links[] = '<small><a href="' . esc_url( $file['download_url'] ) . '">' . sprintf( __( 'Download file%s', 'woocommerce' ), ( count( $download_files ) > 1 ? ' ' . $i . ': ' : ': ' ) ) . esc_html( $file['name'] ) . '</a></small>';
                                }

                                echo '<br/>' . implode( '<br/>', $links );
                            }
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="product-total">
                        <?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php

                if ( $order->has_status( array( 'completed', 'processing' ) ) && ( $purchase_note = get_post_meta( $_product->id, '_purchase_note', true ) ) ) {
                    ?>
                    <tr class="product-purchase-note">
                        <td colspan="3"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( $purchase_note ) ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_items_table', $order );
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', $order ); ?>

<header>
    <h2><?php _e( 'Customer details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
</header>
<dl class="customer_details">
<?php
    if ( $order->billing_email ) echo '<dt>' . __( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</dt><dd>' . $order->billing_email . '</dd>';
    if ( $order->billing_phone ) echo '<dt>' . __( 'Telephone:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</dt><dd>' . $order->billing_phone . '</dd>';

    // Additional customer details hook
    do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details', $order );
?>
</dl>

<?php if ( ! wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && $order->needs_shipping_address() && get_option( 'woocommerce_calc_shipping' ) !== 'no' ) : ?>

<div class="col2-set addresses">

    <div class="col-1">

<?php endif; ?>

        <header class="title">
            <h3><?php _e( 'Billing Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
        </header>
        <address><p>
            <?php
                if ( ! $order->get_formatted_billing_address() ) _e( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); else echo $order->get_formatted_billing_address();
            ?>
        </p></address>

<?php if ( ! wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && $order->needs_shipping_address() && get_option( 'woocommerce_calc_shipping' ) !== 'no' ) : ?>

    </div><!-- /.col-1 -->

    <div class="col-2">

        <header class="title">
            <h3><?php _e( 'Shipping Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
        </header>
        <address><p>
            <?php
                if ( ! $order->get_formatted_shipping_address() ) _e( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); else echo $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();
            ?>
        </p></address>

    </div><!-- /.col-2 -->

</div><!-- /.col2-set -->

<?php endif; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks so much for your time. To add to this... Where we're using `wp_get_post_terms( $_product->id, $tax, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );` Am I wrong in thinking I can display the category slug using `'fields' => 'slug'` Instead of `=> 'name'`?

Comment: Okay so after some searching, I found `<?php wp_get_object_terms( $object_ids, $taxonomies, $args ) ?>` which lead me to using `'fields' => 'slugs'` Which then displayed the product category slug using the function that @helgatheviking kindly shared. Thanks again.