# woocommerce checkout page show cart product categories name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, product, categories

I want to display cart product categories name on woocommerce checkout page Your order details table. For more information please review this screen shot -> http://nimb.ws/xmfXPM

Any one know solutions for my question then please replay me here.

Thanks.

Comment: please check below link for answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414839/woocommerce-adding-product-category-to-order-details-table

Comment: Yes, that's working for me.

Thanks.