# Display all the product attribute details on the email invoice in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, email-notifications

I'm using [WooCommerce - Adding product category to order-details table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24416507/11987538) answer code (via the `woocommerce_order_item_name` filter hook).

It shows how to display category of a product on the email invoice. How can I display all the product attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Product object from its ID and then use woocommerce get_attribute method.

```
$_product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);
$product_attr = $_product->get_attributes();
```

This would return you an array of all attributes assigned to that product, you can just loop through them and display it.

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_get_attributes